# Read XML PHP Internal and External

Tags: php, xml

how do I read this xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response Parte="01" Total="01">
    <Style>
    <color="000000" name="black" Status="3" Erro="0"/>
    <color="0000FF" name="blue" Status="3" Erro="0"/>
    <color="FF0000" name="red" Status="2" Erro="0"/>
    </Style>
</Response>
```

I got to see print_r, but would like to print the lines of color. Ex.:

1: 000000 - black - 3 - 0

2: 0000FF - blue - 3 - 0

3: FF0000 - red - 2 - 0

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid XML.

Comment: Is that always returns the xml webservice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it is not valid xml, you have to deal this output as string

```
$string = '<Response Parte="01" Total="01">
    <Style>
    <color="000000" name="black" Status="3" Erro="0"/>
    <color="0000FF" name="blue" Status="3" Erro="0"/>
    <color="FF0000" name="red" Status="2" Erro="0"/>
    </Style>
</Response>';

preg_match_all('/color="(.*?)" name="(.*?)" Status="(.*?)" Erro="(.*?)"/', $string, $match);
unset($match[0]);
var_dump($match);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Comment: Do you have valid XML?

Comment: so it returns the webservice. just got this

Comment: So you can take this as string and trough preg_match get the values.

Comment: @Mourinha I changed the answer completely, since there was misunderstandind, deal your outpu as string.